# Telegram Bot Forward Message

Tags: python, php, ruby

I would some information about telegram bots. 
Can I forward a message to my bot from a bot that i don't know the token?
I tried to make php, python, ruby code but nothing.
Furthermore i tried to forward by id bot, but documenting on web i can forward only from token

Comment: Please check [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on SO.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question is extremely broad. You want us to explain how bots work, how they communicate, but you don't explain your expertise, so for us to answer we'd have to start with the basics and move up, which is a tutorial and off-topic. Instead, you need to research, try things, and then when you have a particular problem ask a specific question about it. Anything before that point is premature.

Answer (score 2):

Bots can't see messages sent by other bots. It's [one of the explicit limitations](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#what-messages-will-my-bot-get) of the Bot API for Telegram.

> **Why doesn't my bot see messages from other bots?**
>
> Bots talking to each other could potentially get stuck in unwelcome loops. To avoid this, we decided that bots will not be able to see messages from other bots regardless of mode.